# show error message on mui Input with adornment component

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form

I have below mui component which renders and input adornment.
Here is the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k1zn5t?file=/demo.js).

```
<FormControl fullWidth sx={{ m: 1 }} variant="standard">
                  <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-amount">
                    Paid Fees
                  </InputLabel>
                  <Input
                    {...field}
                    name="paidFees"
                    id="standard-adornment-amount"
                    error={Boolean(errors["paidFees"])}
                    startAdornment={
                      <InputAdornment position="start">₹</InputAdornment>
                    }
                  />
                </FormControl>
```

From the [Input API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input/) it accepts prop `error` but there is no prop to pass `helperText` to show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change to using TextField instead of the Input.
Here is the TextField code example you can try.

```js
<TextField
 error
 id="outlined-error-helper-text"
 label="Paid Fees"
 helperText="Incorrect fees."
/>
```